# $\alpha$-particle decay in Heavy nuclei

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation

Can someone explain why heavy nuclei prefer to go through $\alpha$-particle decay instead of nucleon decay?

Answer (score 0):

Nuclei are quantum mechanical "particles" composed out of [protons and neutrons](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/), which themselves are composed out of quarks and a sea of gluons and antiquarks. The basic holding "force" of this is the strong interaction force, modeled [with QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) for the protons and neutrons, and  a spill over force from the protons and neutrons called the [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force).

[Quantum mechanical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus#Shell_models_and_other_quantum_models) have been developed which explain the decay and fission behavior of nuclei.

Hand waving: the alpha particle is very tightly bound, as seen in this [binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve) curve, and in addition, it is stable. Thus within the "bag" containing the nucleons a stable configuration of alphas can exist in unstable nuclei, and the fission  or decay into alphas may be  energetically favored over the emission of a single nucleon, for a particular nucleus.

The models fit this behavior and can predict how other nuclei will fission or decay.